How to get email server back up and running for client on bluehost?
I am a web designer and am working with a client who has been using bluehost for their web & email hosting. Upon finishing their web design, I edited their A @ record to point their domain to web hosting on gohighlevel (where I built their website). I also added a CNAME record to point www to the new web server as well.
Once I did this, my client reported that they stopped receiving emails for all email accounts associated with their domain. After speaking with bluehost IT support, they mentioned their MX record also needed updating. So, the support rep updated their MX record to mail.example.com (don't want to share exact domain name) and said all should be fixed now. After waiting 24 hours for this to propagate, my client is still complaining that they're not receiving emails.
Are there any other DNS records I need to add, update, or remove that would be causing my client to not receive emails?

I did find these instructions. Can't be sure it will be useful. There's a lot of talk of CNAME records.

Whats the domain name?    In order to get mail working you need valid MX records.  There are other useful records like SPF and DKIM records, but these are not strictly speaking required for mail to work.    Make sure your CNAME is only for www - if you have a cname for example.com (ie not www.example.com) that will cause the kinds of problem you describe.

Also, what error is your client getting?    Are their mail server settings using example.com or mail.example.com?   If they are using example.com that would likely be the problem.

Just a heads-up, sometimes MX records can take up to 48 hours to update, but as I understand, it's already been two days. The waiting time depends directly on the TTL.
You can try checking the records yourself for accuracy, for example, using mxtoolbox.
And like the commenter under your question mentioned, make sure to double-check the CNAME records for correctness.

MX records taking 48 hours to update?   In theory yes - but then in theory they could be a month.  In practice MX records should have a much lower TTL - in the region of 1 hour or less is typical.  (gmail.com is 1 hour, outlook.com's MX ttl is 5 minutes)
